# Why does this thread's title appear faint?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

Here's a screenshot of the Travel SE page, taken just now. Look at the middle entry:

[image]

Why is the listing so faint?

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I somehow managed to ignore the b1-b2-visas tag by accident a while back and have been irked by the faint questions, but not so irked to do anything about it. Glad it wasn't just me.

Answer (score 8):

You've chosen to ignore some tags.  (right hand side of main page).  Any questions that appear with that tag on them get greyed out (if selected when you choose said tags).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I hadn't seen that.